# nth-child selector with variable value selecting all elements in explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

Having an jquery nth-child issue in IE, where I can't seem to get a variable assigned to the selector. If i hardcode, this works fine. The variable appears to be selecting each element, rather than the one specified in the variable.

I've tested in Chrome, Firefox, and everything there is find and dandy.
Would love to know why this isn't working in IE. Any ideas?

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var pageNum = 1;

    $('form fieldset').css('display','none');    //hiding all fieldsets
    $('form fieldset:nth-child(' + pageNum + ')').fadeIn('800');   //fading in only the desired fieldset

});
```

**markup:**

```
<form id="EmailSignatureGenerator">
        <fieldset>
            <h3>Personal Details</h3>
            <div><label>First Name:<input id="txtFname" name="txtFname" /></label></div>
            <div><label>Middle Name or Initial: <input id="txtMname" name="txtMname" /></label></div>
            <div><label>Last Name:<input id="txtLname" name="txtLname" /></label></div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h3>Another Fieldset</h3>
            <div><label>First Name:<input id="txtFname" name="txtFname" /></label></div>
            <div><label>Middle Name or Initial: <input id="txtMname" name="txtMname" /></label></div>
            <div><label>Last Name:<input id="txtLname" name="txtLname" /></label></div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h3>Third Fieldset</h3>
            <div><label>First Name:<input id="txtFname" name="txtFname" /></label></div>
            <div><label>Middle Name or Initial: <input id="txtMname" name="txtMname" /></label></div>
            <div><label>Last Name:<input id="txtLname" name="txtLname" /></label></div>
        </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: None at all. It seems it should be a pretty straightforward situation...or so I thought!

Answer (score 1):

It appears this issue was specific to jquery 1.8.3.

I have updated to 1.9.1 and the problem is no longer present.